# How to give 3 relations to same table in Cakephp

Tags: database, cakephp, foreign-keys, models, database-relations

Hi i am new in cake php and can't solve the problem. The problem is I have a table like;

> id                varchar(16)
>
> parent_id         varchar(16)
>
> text              text
>
> user_id               bigint(20)
>
> is_deleted_by_user    bit(1)
>
> is_deleted_by_us  bit(1)
>
> who_deleted           bigint(20)
>
> who_answered      bigint(20)
>
> modified_at           datetime
>
> created_at            datetime

in this table i want to give relations between users table and user_id, who_deleted, who_answered. I mean user_id, who_deleted and who_answered are one user id. How can i give relations between users table and this table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's relatively easy to create multiple relationships to the same model. There's a [section of the documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1046/Multiple-relations-to-the-same-model) dedicated to it. Here's how I've done it for a `Resource` model that has multiple fields associated with a `Binary` model:

```
class Resource extends AppModel {
  public $belongsTo = array ( 
    'PDF' => array (
      'className'  => 'Binary',
      'foreignKey' => 'pdf_file_id'
    ),
    'MSWord' => array (
      'className'  => 'Binary',
      'foreignKey' => 'msword_file_id'
    )
  );

  ... other class code ...
}
```

The `resources` table contains `pdf_file_id` and `msword_file_id` fields which each reference a `Binary` record.

Hope that helps.